# Decrease padding in a GridView in JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, padding, cellpadding

I have a table where in each row there are 4 columns, the columns that I would like to occupy all the space in the row and that did not have such a wide margin. What to do?
The result that I got is this:

[image]

This is the code:

```
  <body>

    <div data-role="page" class="type-interior">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="f">
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <a href="../../" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
    <a href="../nav.html" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="fade">Search</a>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
    <div class="content-primary">   
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
            <li><a href="index.html">
                <div data-role="content"> <div class="ui-grid-c">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" >Block A</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" >Block B</div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-c">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" >Block C</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-d">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" >Block D</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">
            <div data-role="content"> <div class="ui-grid-c">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" >Block 1</div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" ">Block 2</div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-c">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" >Block 3</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-d">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" >Block 4</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the class of Block from **ui-bar ui-bar-e** to **ui-bar ui-bar**:

```
   <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme="e"  >
            <li><a href="index.html">

                <div data-role=""> <div class="ui-grid-c"  >

                    <div class="ui-block-a" >

                    <div class="ui-bar ui-bar" >Block A</div>
                   </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar" >Block B</div> 

                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-c">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar" >Block C</div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-d">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar" >Block D</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">
            <div data-role=""> <div class="ui-grid-c">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar" >Block 1</div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar" ">Block 2</div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-c">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar" >Block 3</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-d">
                        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar" >Block 4</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I removed **div class="content-primary"**

For obtain yellow background I changed the theme with **data-theme="e"**